# Postgresql, retrieve resultset for specific key from json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have Postgres column of JSONB array of objects, looking like this :

```
[{"key": "meetingDate", "value": "2022-08-22"}, {"key": "userName", "value": "Testing User"}]
```

how can i get the result like this

| meetingDate | userName |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-22 | TestingUser |

Comment: Does you array always contain only two elements? What if there are 5 usernames but only 3 meeting dates?

Comment: the array only contains this structure one meeting date and one username

Comment: Would be a lot easier if it was `{"meetingDate": "2022-08-22", "userName": "TestingUser"}`

Comment: but i cant change the structure as the structure i mentioned is required for the business logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.key == "meetingDate").value') #>> '{}' as meetingdate,
       jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.key == "userName").value') #>> '{}' as username
from the_table;
```

`jsonb_path_query_first` returns a `jsonb` value, but there is no direct cast from there to `text`. The `#>> '{}'` is a small hack to convert the `jsonb` value to a `text` value. If you are OK with a `jsonb` value, you can remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Use json_array_elements ([db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NSyXgRSn)).

```sql
with t(v) as (values
  ('[{"key": "meetingDate", "value": "2022-08-22"}, {"key": "userName", "value": "Testing User"}]'::jsonb)
)
select (select a.e->>'value' from json_array_elements(t.v::json) a(e) where a.e->>'key' = 'meetingDate') as meetingDate
     , (select a.e->>'value' from json_array_elements(t.v::json) a(e) where a.e->>'key' = 'userName') as userName
from t
```